# New Bot Channels Registration gets a 403 Forbidden while Testing the Web Chat from within Azure Portal

Tags: azure, botframework

I have a Microsoft Bot Builder application hosted at the following URL

http://hospitalbot.azurewebsites.net

It is an App Service application, works fine when I connect emulators to it.

I decided to register a channel for it so I can talk to my bot using Web Chat so I went to Azure portal and created new `Bot Channels Registration`

[image: Bot registration]

I added the correct endpoint for my bot

[image: Endpoint]

When I talk to my bot using the Chat tester within Azure portal I get a `Couldn't send` error

[image: couldnt send]

Looking at the channel diagnosis I see I am getting 403 forbidden. My endpoint does not have an App ID or password, I don't need one for Emulator. What am I missing?
[image: 403]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create "Bot Channels Registration" on Azure portal, it will help create App ID and password, and you can find/manage that app on **Settings** blade.

[image]

If you forgot the password of that App, you can click **Manage** link and generate new password.

[image]

Then, you can update/set settings for **MicrosoftAppId** and **MicrosoftAppPassword** on **Application Settings** blade of your Azure web app `https://hospitalbot.azurewebsites.net`.

[image]